# Is there a Meter to indicate current Network Activity to the xfce4-panel

Tags: xubuntu, xfce-panel, network-monitoring

I already have a meter on the xfce4 panel which indicates the current CPU load (blue themometer), the current memory load (green thermomeer) and the current swap storage load (a yellow thermometer).

I am looking for one more which shows the current network activity level - either as such a thermometer or even better as something to click on th show the input and output als a graph for say the last quarter of an hour.

Comment: Right click on empty space on a panel and go to Panel>>Panel Preferences. Go to the Item tab. Select add button on the right. There's a plug-in called Network Monitor. Add it to the panel and move it to suitable place if needed. Does it work for you?

Comment: Thank you for the hint. I followed it. But there is no meter, just a box with the word "Net" in it. Can it be applied for LAN and WLAN? Do I have to enter something on the second entry of its properties dialog? What do I have to enter to select it for LAN? What for WLAN? Can I add two of them - one for LAN, one for WLAN?

Comment: The command ip link show gave ma an overview about the networks present in the computer. I concluded that the second one, in my case enp0s25 was the right one for the LAN. But the samling time of 0.25s was a bit short. Setting it to 1 second made it show up. One should set the upper scsle ends for incoming and for outgoing traffic to what one expect, e.g. 50 KiB/s incomint, 1 KiB/s outgoing. It would be nice if the scales could be made logarithmic! It is possible to place two instances, one for WLAN, the pother for LAN. I called them W and L.

Answer (score 1):

The command

```
ip link show
```

gave me an overview about the network adapter names of my computer.

From observing results of `ip link show` with the LAN pluged/unplugged and the WLAN enabled/disabled, I concluded that in my case `enp0s25` designates my LAN adapter and `wlp3s0` designates my WLAN adapter.

But the sampling time of 0.25s was a bit too short. Setting it to 1 second made the activity bar show up when I let firefox show a Bing map. One should set the upper scale ends for incoming and for outgoing traffic to what one expects. I tried it with 50 KiB/s incoming, 1 KiB/s outgoing because in most cases my question is: "is there any network activity".

It would be nice if the scales could be made logarithmic (however since the logarithm of 0 is -Infinty, clipping off all network activity below one packet per sampling)!

It *is* possible to place e.g. two instances of Network Monitor: one for WLAN, the other for LAN. I called them W and L. - Thank you, HattinGokbori87!